# Add module to Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I am working on orchard CMS (version 1.8.1) sites with multiple language, I found this one (https://github.com/qt1/orchard_contrib-RM.Localization) is useful, and I would like to add this to my site, but failed to work (I just copied it into, but picker widget cannot be found in dashboard), may someone know how to do and give me some advice?

Regards,
David

Comment: Have you enabled the module in dashboard/Modules? Have you checked if it compiles and doesn't throw errors? (in the logs)

Comment: I have enabled all in dashboard with no header error and no error in app_data/logs. If it need compile, do I need to find orchard source project to build with it?

Comment: If it doesn't compile it would create an error in the logs

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this module in you Orchard app, you need to add it the the Orchard.sln and compile the application - then the module will be visible in *Modules* section of the dashboard.

You can also try using an existing package from the [Orchard Gallery](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/Modules?q=localization)

1. Download a package
2. Go to Modules, and enable **Packaging** module
3. Go to Modules -> Installed and click *Install a module from your computer*
4. Browse the package and click *Install*
5. Now enable the installed module